# Using GPU with containers and Container Optimized OS in Google Cloud VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu, google-compute-engine, google-container-os

I would like to run a custom Docker image with GPU on Google Compute Engine.
I have built and pushed the image to the Google Container Registry.
It seems logical to use Container-Optimized OS for a host machine in Google Cloud Engine since I don't need any extra soft on the host machine except Docker, Nvidia GPU drivers and `nvidia-container-runtime`.

I managed to install nvidia-drivers with [this solution](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cos-gpu-installer).

But I can't run my Docker image with GPU (using `--gpu all` option) without nvidia-container runtime. [This step is specified in official Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#access-an-nvidia-gpu).

Is there a way to install nvidia-container-runtime on Container-Optimized OS in Google Cloud VM?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to set `--gpu all`, because this is the default option for [nvidia-container-runtime](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-container-runtime). The assumption, that you don't need anything else is wrong, because it requires [libnvidia-container](https://github.com/NVIDIA/libnvidia-container).

To precisely answer the question: No, because `libnvidia-container` needs to be installed on the OS and `nvidia-container-runtime` needs to be installed within the K8s container. The one exposes an interface - and the other connects it. And so the one is useless without the other.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I mentioned that I am interested in Google COmpute Enginer instance, not k8s cluster.

Comment: Does it mean that it's impossible to run containers with GPU on Google Compute instance?

Comment: If you wish to access the GPU from within Docker, you need to install both components... and you cannot run the run-time directly on GCE. It's GPU <-> kernel module (driver) <-> `libnvidia-container` <-> `nvidia-container-runtime`. It's complicated, but this is based upon several abstraction layers. And I don't think that there would be much difference, in between Container Engine & Compute Engine.

Comment: And that `--gpu` switch is merely to use different GPU with different Docker containers.

Comment: my question was not about `--gpu` switch